# How can I get overlapping RegEx matches in Java?

Tags: java, regex

For example, using the pattern

```regex
[a-z]{2}
```

Over the string `bcd`, the only match will be `[bc]`. Instead, I'd like to get `[bc, cd]`.

Comment: Note: There is currently no method (AFAIK) to get all matches that can start at the same index. e.g. `a*` for `aaa`, which can have 4 matches at index 0. Marko Topolnik's answer covers the case where you want to get at most 1 match at each index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this with a lookahead that involves a capture group:

```regex
(?=([a-z]{2})).
```

You'll need a loop involving `Matcher.find` and query the matcher each time with `group(1)` to get your match. The main regex match itself is irrelevant and should be ignored.

Comment: Why would you need the lookahead? And doesn't the `.` at the end prevent matches that consist of only the last character?

Comment: `And doesn't the . at the end prevent matches that consist of only the last character?` No it doesn't. But it does prevent an empty match (well, if we use a pattern that can match empty string). Look-ahead is one clean way to approach this and you don't have to care about boundary cases.

Comment: @escitalopram I haven' tried this out so I put `.` in there conservatively. I think the whole thing works without the dot just as well.

Answer (score 2):

Repeatedly use [`Matcher.find(int start)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28int%29) and [`Matcher.start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start%28%29) to find out, at which String index to look next.

```
String haystack="bcd";
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(haystack);
int lookIndex=0;
while(lookIndex < haystack.length() && m.find(lookIndex)) {
    lookIndex=m.start()+1;
    System.out.println("Found " + m.group());
}
```

Comment: It is indeed one solution, but you would have to be careful when the pattern can match empty string...

Comment: It is adjusted to avoid OutOfBoundsException now. Also successfully tested it with a pattern matching an empty String.